# Calculating velocities and acceleration in python for large numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I am working on a particle tracking code where my array is stored like this:

```
x_pos   y_pos    path#   slice#
1       10       1       1
2       11       1       2
3       12       1       3
5       2        2       1
7       4        2       2
9       6        2       3
11      8        2       4
...
2       6        N       100
```

where each path number corresponds to a trajectory of a single particle and the slice number is the image number where the particle is contained.

I would like to calculate the velocity and acceleration for each path (for both each segment of the path and then for the overall path). Currently, I am using (assuming my time step is 1):

```
vel_x = np.diff(data['x_Pos']) 
acc = np.diff(vel_x)
```

This works well, but I then have to go through the array and take out incorrect values (ie. where the path# changes). Does anyone know of a fast way to do this since my array has a length close to 1 million? Or, a better way to calculate velocities and accelerations?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated since I am relatively new to python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `np.where`:

```
vel_x = np.where(np.diff(data['path#'])==0, np.diff(data['x_Pos']), np.inf)
```

result ("inf" is just to show the data is not valid):

```
array([  1.,   1.,  inf,   2.,   2.,   2.])
```

Comment: I think `np.nan` would be better than `np.inf`. If you divide a number by an invalid value you would expect another invalid value, not 0.

Comment: Thanks RootTwo and @Goyo. I ended up doing something similar, but I think your answer is much easier!
- Sort the array
    `results = results.sort_values(by=['Count','Slice'])`
- Set the index as count/slice
    `results = results.set_index(['Count','Slice'])`
- Loop through the index
    `for ii in results.index.get_level_values('Count').unique():
        results['Vel_x'][ii].iloc[:-1]=np.diff(results['X'][ii])
        results['Vel_y'][ii].iloc[:-1]=np.diff(results['Y'][ii])`